# PostgreSQL archive_command on Windows

Tags: postgresql, replication, windows

What is the best method for WAL log transfer on Windows?

I have two servers with Windows Server 2008, PostgreSQL 9.0 64bit.

Servers do not have any shared SAN disk, they are on different hosts, different subnets.

Files from the first server must be transferred in reliable way to the second server.

Archive location must be protected by password.

I have tried to use free rsync/rsyncd solution called DeltaCopy, but permissions part is hard for me. The service does not want to run under "postgres" account. It runs as System Local acount but the files are not readable by postgres. If I use `incoming chmod` option in `deltacd.conf` (aka `rsyncd.conf`), it "garbles" Windows file permissions, so I have problems with some actions on file's "Security" tab.

I would like some solution which is reliable, and easy to setup and maintain.

One respondent suggested `xcopy` - but it has no option to provide passowrd from command line or password file.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered [Robocopy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145%28WS.10%29.aspx)? It is [able to copy NTFS ACLs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robocopy). I guess you might need to have postgres running under the same Domain Account on source and target if possible but I'm probably out of my depth talking about such things.